# An equivalence concerning analytic continuation along arcs (Ahlfors)

Tags: complex-analysis

In Ahlfors' Complex Analysis text, page 295, he discusses the Monodromy theorem. As he begins to prove the theorem he states:

> To begin with we note that continuation along an arc of the form $\gamma \gamma^{-1}$
>   will always lead back to the initial germ. Similarly, continuation along
>   an arc of the form $\sigma_1(\gamma \gamma^{-1})\sigma_2$ will have the same effect as continuation
>   along $\sigma_1 \sigma_2$. *For this reason, to say that the continuations along $\gamma_1$ and $\gamma_2$
>   lead to the same end result is equivalent to saying that continuation along
>   $\gamma_1 \gamma_2^{-1}$ leads back to the initial germ.*

I'm having troubles with the part in italics. Clearly I need to use the equivalence between $\sigma_1 (\gamma \gamma^{-1}) \sigma_2$ and $\sigma_1 \sigma_2$ with suitable arcs $\sigma_1,\sigma_2, \gamma$, in order to establish the claimed equivalence.

I tried taking $\sigma_1=\gamma_1,\sigma_2=\gamma_2^{-1}$, and several different $\gamma$'s, but I don't seem to get anywhere.

Please help me understand how to prove the statement in italics. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us denote the property of two paths starting in the same point $z_0$ that analytic continuation of a germ $\mathbf{f}$ along the two paths leads to the same end result (the two paths then must necessarily have the same endpoint) by $\gamma_1 \approx \gamma_2$.

Evidently, if $\gamma$ is any path starting in the endpoint of $\gamma_1$, we have

$$\gamma_1 \approx \gamma_2 \Rightarrow \gamma_1\gamma \approx \gamma_2\gamma.$$

Thus, starting from $\gamma_1\approx\gamma_2$, we obtain

$$\gamma_1 \approx \gamma_2 \Rightarrow \gamma_1 \gamma_2^{-1} \approx \gamma_2\gamma_2^{-1} \Rightarrow \gamma_1\gamma_2^{-1} \approx c_{z_0}$$

where $c_{z_0}$ is the constant path in $z_0$. The last follows because $\gamma_2\gamma_2^{-1}\sim c_{z_0}$ (homotopy).

Conversely,

$$\gamma_1\gamma_2^{-1} \approx c_{z_0} \Rightarrow \gamma_1\gamma_2^{-1}\gamma_2 \approx c_{z_0}\gamma_2 \Rightarrow \gamma_1 \approx \gamma_2,$$

since $\gamma_1\gamma_2^{-1}\gamma_2 \sim \gamma_1$ and $c_{z_0}\gamma_2 \sim \gamma_2$.

You just "multiply" with constant paths and "inverses", and since you can cancel constant paths and compositions of the form $\gamma\gamma^{-1}$ (or $\gamma^{-1}\gamma$), it turns out to be essentially the same proof as $f(x_1) = f(x_2) \iff x_1x_2^{-1} \in \ker f$ for group homomorphisms $f$. (Well, in a way. Composition of paths is far enough away from forming a group. It becomes that when considering closed paths, modulo homotopy.)

Comment: Thanks Daniel. I think that using the homotopy relation $(\sim)$ in order to prove your relation $(\approx)$ is a result of the monodromy theorem, which I didn't prove yet. However, I think that the [uniqueness of analytic continuation along a curve](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/615820/an-equivalence-concerning-analytic-continuation-along-arcs-ahlfors) suffices to prove that $\gamma \gamma^{-1} \approx c_{z_0}$: Since tracing $\overline{\gamma}$ and then reversing that, is a continuous candidate for the analytic continuation along that curve, and it is unique. Is that right?

Comment: Yes, that is sufficient. And of course also to add or remove constant paths ad libitum.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have Ahlfors in front of me, but I assume he's using the convention that $\alpha \beta$ describes the arc $\alpha$ followed by the arc $\beta$ (where the starting point of $\beta$ is the ending point of $\alpha$.
For an arc $\gamma$ let $T_\gamma$ be the operator taking a germ at the starting point of $\gamma$ to its continuation along $\gamma$, a germ at the ending point of $\gamma$.  Then $T_{\gamma_1 \gamma_2} = T_{\gamma_2} T_{\gamma_1}$, and
$T_\gamma = (T_{\gamma^{-1}})^{-1}$.  It follows that 
$T_{\gamma_1} = T_{\gamma_2}$ iff ${T_{\gamma_2}}^{-1} T_{\gamma_1} = T_{\gamma_2^{-1}} T_{\gamma_1} = T_{\gamma_1 \gamma_2^{-1}}$ is the identity operator.